# Finding text length within a divs children

Tags: javascript, jquery

So i have an array of divs. each div contains three span elements. Each span element can contain any number of digits.

This is what i have so far:

```
var arrayOfDivs = $(".avgMaxClass");
                $.each(arrayOfDivs, function (index, value) {


                });
```

what i want to do is calculate the total length of all the text within all the spans within the div im iterating through. I can't figure it how to do that.

EDIT:
To be clear i don't want the total text length of all the divs. I want the text length of the current div that im iterating through

Comment: `$(".avgMaxClass span").text().length`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just iterate over the div and find its length.

```
$(".avgMaxClass").each(function(){
    var thisDivsLength = $(this).find('span').text().length;
    alert("Current div's length: " + thisDivsLength);
});
```

`$.each` is for non-jQuery objects. Use `$.fn.each` instead.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/7ggjdx14/5/)

Comment: What about text that's not inside a `span`? OP doesn't want that counted.

Comment: @PaulRoub he didn't specify that he had anything other than spans.. so

Comment: I only have spans within theese divs. But i want to know the text length of each div, that is because im gonna change fontsize depending on the total text length of the div.

Comment: and your suggestion doesn't work. It only finds the length of the first span.

Comment: I want to extract the text length of each div im iterating through. Not the total length of all the text in all the divs.

Comment: @steffokeffo glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 4):

```
$(".avgMaxClass span").text().length;
```

<kbd>[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/7ggjdx14/)</kbd>

**Edit:**

As you stated in your comment that you want to know the length for each DIV, here is another way using `jQuery.each()`:

```
var avgMaxClass = $('.avgMaxClass');

$.each(avgMaxClass, function(i,item) {

    // Output span text length for each item
    console.log($("span", item).text().length); 
});
```

<kbd>[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/7ggjdx14/6/)</kbd>

Comment: Have you just copypasted my comment as an answer? ;)

Comment: @pawel sorry, no I didn't, but that happens sometimes ;-)

Comment: @A.Wolff no, it doesn't, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @MrUpsidown You are correct, i forgot about this and the DOC clearly says that you are correct ;)

Comment: Yes. Updated with a fiddle.

Comment: @epascarello why did you say that?

Comment: but i want to know each divs text length as im looping through my arrayofDivs

Comment: @MrUpsidown usually, when getter function is used on a collection of jQuery objects, only the first one will be returned. I suppose that's what made him to say that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a selector to get the `div`s and `span`s at the same time, or to split the logic and show both parts individually, you can use two selectors and loop over the results of each.

```js
var total = 0;
$(".avgMaxClass").each(function(index, value) {
  $(value).find("span").each(function(cindex, child) {
    total += $(child).text().length;
  });
});

$("#result").text("Total length: " + total);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="avgMaxClass">
  <span>1</span>
  <span>12</span>
  <span>123</span>
</div>
<div class="avgMaxClass">
  <span>1234</span>
  <pre>12345</pre>
  <span>12345</span>
</div>
<div class="avgMaxClass">
  <span>123456</span>
  <span>1234567</span>
  <span>12345678</span>
</div>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: I want to know each divs text length as im looping through it. Your code returns 3 on every loop

Comment: That's because I happened to put three digits in each span.

Comment: oh you are right, yepp, this worked best of all the solutions.

Comment: well, it doesnt work now when i check. i created this jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/f1yq0tdz/
the first log shows 5, then 3, then 5. It should show 13 cause thats the total length of the entire div. I rechecked your example and it gives me the wrong result.

Comment: That's because your separator is `span` that matches the selector, and has the text `" | "` (three additional characters). IF you have a class like that on each span you want to count, you should include it in the inner selector: http://jsfiddle.net/f1yq0tdz/1/